# How can I get test_value in PyMC(PyMC4)?

Tags: bayesian, pymc, bayesian-networks

I am a newbie in Bayesian and Probabilistic inference, and sorry for this basic question. Recently I am following some examples in Bayesian Methods. And, the examples require me to use "tag.test_value." However, I am trying to use PyMC rather than PyMC3, so there is an error using the sentence. Although I tried to use others such as *init_value, initial_value*, it does not work...

Could you kindly let me know alternatives for that sentence to check the initial value in PyMC (that was originally *test value* in PyMC3)?

```
    a = pm.Uniform("b", 0, 50)
    print(a.tag.test_value)
```

`AttributeError: 'ValidatingScratchpad' object has no attribute 'test_value`

Comment: pymc4 uses Aesera which in turn has the function `a.get_test_value()` but when I try out your example code I get the error `aesara.graph.utils.TestValueError: b has no test value` so it seems like contrary to pymc3 a test value is not automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Aesara does not compute test value by default. You need to set  `aesara.config.compute_test_value = "warn"`. Then you can call `a.get_test_value()`. Hope this helps!